# Test Apache Felix with Java 8 and JavaFX

Tags: osgi, javafx-2, javafx, apache-felix, java-8

I'm working on example with JavaFX 2.2 and Java 8. I created this simple Apache Felix Activator:

***Activator:***

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator
{

    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception
    {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                stage = new Stage();
                BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
                Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 200);
                pane.setCenter(new Label("This is a JavaFX Scene in a Stage"));
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Main Module is loaded!");

    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception
    {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                stage.close();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Main Module is unloaded!");
    }
}
```

***POM***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>DX-57</groupId>
    <artifactId>DX-57_Main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>DX-57_Main OSGi Bundle</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                        <Bundle-Activator>dx57.dx._main.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Export-Package>*</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build-for-felix</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.main</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- To include a shell:
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.gogo.shell</artifactId>
                    <version>0.10.0</version>
                </dependency>
                -->
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>compile</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <pathconvert property="plugins.jars" pathsep="${path.separator}">
                                            <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                            <map from="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes" to=""/>
                                        </pathconvert>
                                        <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="bundles">
                                            <path path="${plugins.jars}"/>
                                            <mapper>
                                                <chainedmapper>
                                                    <flattenmapper/>
                                                    <globmapper from="*" to="file:modules/*" casesensitive="no"/>
                                                </chainedmapper>
                                            </mapper>
                                        </pathconvert>
                                        <propertyfile file="${project.build.directory}/config.properties">
                                            <entry key="felix.auto.start" value="${bundles} file:modules/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>
                                            <entry key="org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation" value="*"/>
                                        </propertyfile>
                                        <copy file="${maven.dependency.org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar.path}" tofile="${project.build.directory}/felix.jar"/>
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>create-executable-jar</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly/felix.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>run-on-felix</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.main</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.gogo.shell:0.6.1 useless from Maven since stdin is swallowed -->
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <property name="vm.args" value=""/>
                                <pathconvert property="plugins.jars" pathsep="${path.separator}">
                                    <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                    <map from="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes" to=""/>
                                </pathconvert>
                                <makeurl property="urls" separator=" ">
                                    <path path="${plugins.jars}"/>
                                    <path location="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>
                                </makeurl>
                                <propertyfile file="${project.build.directory}/run.properties">
                                    <entry key="felix.auto.start" value="${urls}"/>
                                    <entry key="felix.auto.deploy.action" value="uninstall,install,update,start"/>
                                    <entry key="org.osgi.framework.storage" value="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}felix-cache"/>
                                    <entry key="org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation" value="*"/>
                                </propertyfile>
                                <makeurl property="run.properties.url" file="${project.build.directory}/run.properties"/>
                                <java fork="true" jar="${maven.dependency.org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar.path}">
                                    <sysproperty key="felix.config.properties" value="${run.properties.url}"/>
                                    <jvmarg line="${vm.args}"/>
                                </java>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

***Error:***

```
[rcbandit@Laptop felix-framework_JavaFX]$ /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -jar bin/felix.jar
ERROR: Bundle DX-57.Main [1] Error starting file:/home/rcbandit/Desktop/test/felix-framework_JavaFX/bundle/DX-57_Main-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle DX-57.Main [1].)
java.lang.ClassCastException: dx57.dx._main.Activator cannot be cast to org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:4336)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2141)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2064)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1291)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g!
```

I added external packages into the file config.properties:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javafx.application, \
com.sun.browser.plugin, \
com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx, \
com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui, \
com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.resources, \
com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.resources.image, \
com.sun.glass.events, \
com.sun.glass.ui, \
com.sun.glass.ui.delegate, \
com.sun.glass.ui.gtk, \
com.sun.glass.ui.mac, \
com.sun.glass.ui.win, \
com.sun.glass.ui.x11, \
com.sun.glass.utils, \
com.sun.javafx, \
com.sun.javafx.animation, \
com.sun.javafx.animation.transition, \
com.sun.javafx.applet, \
com.sun.javafx.application, \
com.sun.javafx.beans, \
com.sun.javafx.beans.annotations, \
com.sun.javafx.beans.event, \
com.sun.javafx.binding, \
com.sun.javafx.charts, \
com.sun.javafx.collections, \
com.sun.javafx.collections.annotations, \
com.sun.javafx.collections.transformation, \
com.sun.javafx.css, \
com.sun.javafx.css.converters, \
com.sun.javafx.css.parser, \
com.sun.javafx.cursor, \
com.sun.javafx.effect, \
com.sun.javafx.embed, \
com.sun.javafx.event, \
com.sun.javafx.font, \
com.sun.javafx.fxml, \
com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder, \
com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression, \
com.sun.javafx.geom, \
com.sun.javafx.geom.transform, \
com.sun.javafx.iio, \
com.sun.javafx.iio.bmp, \
com.sun.javafx.iio.common, \
com.sun.javafx.iio.gif, \
com.sun.javafx.iio.jpeg, \
com.sun.javafx.iio.png, \
com.sun.javafx.image, \
com.sun.javafx.image.impl, \
com.sun.javafx.jmx, \
com.sun.javafx.logging, \
com.sun.javafx.menu, \
com.sun.javafx.perf, \
com.sun.javafx.property, \
com.sun.javafx.property.adapter, \
com.sun.javafx.robot, \
com.sun.javafx.robot.impl, \
com.sun.javafx.runtime, \
com.sun.javafx.runtime.async, \
com.sun.javafx.runtime.eula, \
com.sun.javafx.scene, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.control, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.caspian, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.input, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.region, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.paint, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.shape, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.text, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.transform, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.web, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.web.behavior, \
com.sun.javafx.scene.web.skin, \
com.sun.javafx.sg, \
com.sun.javafx.sg.prism, \
com.sun.javafx.stage, \
com.sun.javafx.tk, \
com.sun.javafx.tk.desktop, \
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum, \
com.sun.javafx.util, \
com.sun.media.jfxmedia, \
com.sun.media.jfxmedia.control, \
com.sun.media.jfxmedia.effects, \
com.sun.media.jfxmedia.events, \
com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator, \
com.sun.media.jfxmedia.logging, \
com.sun.media.jfxmedia.track, \
com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl, \
com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform, \
com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer, \
com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.java, \
com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.osx, \
com.sun.openpisces, \
com.sun.prism, \
com.sun.prism.camera, \
com.sun.prism.d3d, \
com.sun.prism.d3d.hlsl, \
com.sun.prism.image, \
com.sun.prism.impl, \
com.sun.prism.impl.packrect, \
com.sun.prism.impl.paint, \
com.sun.prism.impl.ps, \
com.sun.prism.impl.shape, \
com.sun.prism.j2d, \
com.sun.prism.j2d.paint, \
com.sun.prism.paint, \
com.sun.prism.ps, \
com.sun.prism.render, \
com.sun.prism.shader, \
com.sun.prism.shape, \
com.sun.prism.tkal, \
com.sun.prism.util.tess, \
com.sun.prism.util.tess.impl.tess, \
com.sun.scenario, \
com.sun.scenario.animation, \
com.sun.scenario.animation.shared, \
com.sun.scenario.effect, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.hw, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.hw.d3d, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.hw.d3d.hlsl, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.sw, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.state, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.sw, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.sw.java, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.sw.sse, \
com.sun.scenario.effect.light, \
com.sun.t2k, \
com.sun.webpane.perf, \
com.sun.webpane.platform, \
com.sun.webpane.platform.event, \
com.sun.webpane.platform.graphics, \
com.sun.webpane.sg, \
com.sun.webpane.sg.prism, \
com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.resources, \
com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.theme, \
com.sun.webpane.sg.theme, \
com.sun.webpane.webkit, \
com.sun.webpane.webkit.dom, \
com.sun.webpane.webkit.network, \
com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.about, \
com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.data, \
com.sun.webpane.webkit.unicode, \
javafx.animation, \
javafx.beans, \
javafx.beans.binding, \
javafx.beans.property, \
javafx.beans.property.adapter, \
javafx.beans.value, \
javafx.collections, \
javafx.concurrent, \
javafx.embed.swing, \
javafx.embed.swt, \
javafx.event, \
javafx.fxml, \
javafx.geometry, \
javafx.scene, \
javafx.scene.canvas, \
javafx.scene.chart, \
javafx.scene.control, \
javafx.scene.control.cell, \
javafx.scene.effect, \
javafx.scene.image, \
javafx.scene.input, \
javafx.scene.layout, \
javafx.scene.media, \
javafx.scene.paint, \
javafx.scene.shape, \
javafx.scene.text, \
javafx.scene.transform, \
javafx.scene.web, \
javafx.stage, \
javafx.util, \
javafx.util.converter, \
org.osgi.framework.wiring, \
netscape.javascript
```

Any idea how to fix the problem?

***UPDATE***

After removing `<Export-Package>*</Export-Package>` I get this error:

```
[rcbandit@Laptop felix-framework_JavaFX]$ /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -jar bin/felix.jar
ERROR: Bundle DX-57.Main [1] Error starting file:/home/rcbandit/Desktop/test/felix-framework_JavaFX/bundle/DX-57_Main-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle DX-57.Main [1].)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:201)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:196)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:52)
    at dx57.dx._main.Activator.start(Activator.java:20)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2146)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2064)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1291)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g!
```

Comment: "with JavaFX 2.2 and Java 8", I guess you mean "with JavaFX 8 and Java SE 8"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaFX applications depend on packages from the JavaFX APIs, such as `javafx.application` and several others. Since it looks like you have built your bundle with Maven Bundle Plugin, your bundle already has these dependencies declared. This is a good thing.

In Java 8 the `javafx.*` packages are provided by the base JRE. However OSGi does not automatically export *every* package from the JRE, simply because all JREs have a bunch of non-standard packages (e.g. `com.sun.*` etc) that normal application code should not have access to. Therefore OSGi only makes available the packages that are defined by the relevant JCP Specification for the version of Java that you are using. For example packages such as `javax.swing`, `org.w3c.dom`, etc.

Since JavaFX is not a standard, there is no JCP Specification for JavaFX, and OSGi does not export the `javafx.*` packages. However you can configure OSGi to do this for you by setting the following configuration property when you launch OSGi:

`org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javafx.application,...`

**NB** I have shown how to add the `javafx.application` package to your runtime. It is likely you will need to add several more, i.e. all of the packages from the JavaFX API. I am not sufficiently familar with JavaFX to list these, but they should be easy enough for you to find.

Comment: I looked at your update. This makes no sense. You are trying to import a package named "osgi.wiring.package"?? There is no such package. Did you add this dependency explicitly? Please show more information about what you did please.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Are you reading these replies?? You have added an invalid dependency. Please show the pom for the bundle.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Looks like you pasted the wrong one. The bundle `DX-57.testr` is the one that failed.

Comment: @PeterPenzov I don't think that was a good idea... now the answer doesn't relate to the question. Oh well. Anyway the latest problem is that you have said `<Export-Package>*</Export-Package>`. Please remove that line.

Comment: I updated the post again after I remove `<Export-Package>*</Export-Package>`

Comment: @PeterPenzov That's now a JavaFX problem, not OSGi. You need to work out how to properly initialise the JavaFX runtime I guess. Please stop multiplexing more and more questions onto this one stackoverflow page. Just mark the question answered and post your latest problem in a new question.

Answer (score 6):

I have recently released a first Early Access version of [Drombler FX](http://wiki.drombler.org/), a modular Rich Client Platform for JavaFX based on OSGi and Maven (POM-first; uses Apache Felix by default).

You can read more about it here: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2012/12/drombler-fx-building-modular-javafx.html

Getting Startet: http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted

I recenttly tried to run it with a pre-release of Java SE 8 and it worked so far, though I haven't specified the system packages for Java SE 8 yet, so I'm not sure if everything works/ if you have access to everything.