# OSGI using Apache Felix + JavaFx 8: missing requirement (osgi.wiring.package=javafx.application)

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix, javafx-8

I'm working on example with JavaFX with Java 8 ea b121 and Apache Felix. Starting with the Activator like in the question [test-apache-felix-with-java-8-and-javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753429/test-apache-felix-with-java-8-and-javafx) everything compiles fine.

According to the answers of the mentioned stackoverflow-question I extended the properties for the framework :

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javafx.application, ...
```

My POM is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>example-base-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example.base</groupId>
        <relativePath>../example-base-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>example-base-ui</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <bundle.namespace>example.base.ui</bundle.namespace>
        <bundle.symbolicName>${project.artifactId}</bundle.symbolicName>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                            <Bundle-Activator>${bundle.namespace}.TestActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

On runtime I end up with this error:

(org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle nxdiagnost-base-ui [1]: Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javafx.application))

Is there anything else I need to consider? Is JavaFx already in classpath with the current Java 8 ea?

Comment: The error suggests that the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` setting hasn't been correctly applied, i.e. the `javafx.application` package is not exported from the system bundle. But I don't see anything wrong with the information you have given, so some debugging is required. Please install the Felix Gogo shell and paste the output of the following command: `inspect cap osgi.wiring.package 0`. This will list the actual exports of the system bundle.

Comment: Thanks you gave me the right direction. The `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra`-settings were not applied when launching felix. Now I am at the same point of correctly initializing JavaFx as here [test-apache-felix-with-java-8-and-javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753429/test-apache-felix-with-java-8-and-javafx).

Comment: I found a solution to start the javafx-bundle by looking how the javafx example is launched given the "osgi-snippets" found at [http://blog.admadic.com/](http://blog.admadic.com/2013/01/osgi-snippets.html).