# org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve missing requirement osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javafx.application)

Tags: java, maven, javafx, osgi

I am trying to run my Maven OSGi JavaFx project, but I keep getting the following error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve launcher [4](R 4.0): missing requirement [launcher [4](R 4.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javafx.application) Unresolved requirements: [[launcher [4](R 4.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javafx.application)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)
    at impl.App.loadBundles(App.java:84)
    at impl.App.initialize(App.java:60)
    at impl.App.main(App.java:26)
```

`mvn clean package` works perfectly, and I get my project jars generated.

Some reading around has let me to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753429/test-apache-felix-with-java-8-and-javafx#16755214) :

> JavaFX applications depend on packages from the JavaFX APIs, such as javafx.application and several others.
>
> In Java 8 the javafx.* packages are provided by the base JRE. However OSGi does not automatically export every package from the JRE, simply because all JREs have a bunch of non-standard packages (e.g. com.sun.* etc) that normal application code should not have access to. Therefore OSGi only makes available the packages that are defined by the relevant JCP Specification for the version of Java that you are using. For example packages such as javax.swing, org.w3c.dom, etc.
>
> Since JavaFX is not a standard, there is no JCP Specification for JavaFX, and OSGi does not export the javafx.* packages. However you can configure OSGi to do this for you by setting the following configuration property when you launch OSGi:
>
> `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javafx.application,...`

How can I implement the above suggestion, or what can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your App where you construct the framework object, you pass in a Map of configuration parameters. You can set the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` property in the map with the desired javafx packages.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you please illustrate @BJ Hargrave?

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev What is missing from the answer BJ gave, and the one I gave in my answer to the question you linked? I have marked your question as a duplicate.