# Loading javaFx into Apache felix

Tags: java, swing, maven, javafx, apache-felix

I'm trying to load javafx into a swing based software that follows the OSGi implementation.
The thing is, whenever i try to instanciate any class from FX it gives me ClassDefNotFoundException.

I already tried some solutions from other posts but nothing changes.

This is part of my POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>!javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel,*</Import-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>
                        *;scope=compile;inline=true,
                        javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;scope=compile;inline=true
                    </Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-StripVersion>true</Embed-StripVersion>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This is the command that gives me the exception:

```
JFXPanel J = new JFXPanel();
```

And this is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
at br.com.test.SampleTool.<init>(SampleTool.java:87)
at br.com.test.SampleToolFactory.createDataExplorerView(SampleToolFactory.java:62)
at org.weasis.base.ui.internal.Activator.dataExplorerChanged(Activator.java:118)
at org.weasis.base.ui.internal.Activator.lambda$serviceChanged$2(Activator.java:110)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerWiring.getClassByDelegation(ExtensionManager.java:1010)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1595)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1525)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 18 more
```

Comment: have you tried  exporting the packages using command line Dorg.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel ,  http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html

Comment: I did that in the vm arguments on eclipse, i also tried to include the Class into the configuration file. Maybe it could be a problem with the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This instruction need to be fixed:

```
<Embed-Dependency>
*;scope=compile;inline=true,
javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;scope=compile;inline=true
</Embed-Dependency>
```

**Embed-Dependency** works with **artifacts**, but `javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel` is a **class**.

Therefore, you need to specify artifacts that have all the JavaFX classes you need.

Then you should remove this line :

`<Import-Package>!javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel,*</Import-Package>`

Because you want to import this class.

I believe, you are looking for something like this:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Embed-Dependency>groupId=javafx;artifactId=jfxrt;version=8.0;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>                            
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Alternatively, you can add JavaFX as system packages: [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16755214/1968258)

Comment: Thank you this worked, your answer was very helpful.